# Load/Bind event for Google maps marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, events, google-maps-markers

I am loading map using Google maps api and creating markers on the map.

Now I want to display a small box under marker to display some info.. Its not an infowindow.
The box should appear while loading of the map itself..

These are the issues..

> 1. To refer the marker, the marker should have some Id.. Then only I can use it.   So, how to set an Id for the marker?
> 2. I need a load/bind event for the marker to bind the small box to the marker.   Is there any events like load/bind for marker?

Anyone please.. help..

Answer (score 1):

Download the `Marker with Label` library from the link below

http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries#MarkerWithLabel

and use the marker as follows;

```
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
   position: new google.maps.latLng(28.32323,78.33232),
   map: map,
   draggable: true,
   raiseOnDrag: true,
   labelContent: "Your content should go here",
   labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(3, 30),
   labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
   labelInBackground: false
});
```

Comment: No. I have already seen on MarkerWithLabel. But, I dont want to use this. This causes performance issue. It will take more time to load 1000s of markers..